# How do I print all the -XX parameters of the Java virtual machine

Tags: java, jvm

How can I get a list of all arguments supported by -xx on the command line without referring to the specification?

```
java -X     
-Xmixed           mixed mode execution (default)
-Xint             interpreted mode execution only
-Xbootclasspath:<directories and zip/jar files separated by :>
                  set search path for bootstrap classes and resources
-Xbootclasspath/a:<directories and zip/jar files separated by :>
                  append to end of bootstrap class path
-Xbootclasspath/p:<directories and zip/jar files separated by :>
                  prepend in front of bootstrap class path
-Xdiag            show additional diagnostic messages
-Xnoclassgc       disable class garbage collection
-Xincgc           enable incremental garbage collection
-Xloggc:<file>    log GC status to a file with time stamps
-Xbatch           disable background compilation
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
-Xprof            output cpu profiling data
-Xfuture          enable strictest checks, anticipating future default
-Xrs              reduce use of OS signals by Java/VM (see documentation)
-Xcheck:jni       perform additional checks for JNI functions
-Xshare:off       do not attempt to use shared class data
-Xshare:auto      use shared class data if possible (default)
-Xshare:on        require using shared class data, otherwise fail.
-XshowSettings    show all settings and continue
-XshowSettings:all
                  show all settings and continue
-XshowSettings:vm
                  show all vm related settings and continue
-XshowSettings:system
                  (Linux Only) show host system or container
                  configuration and continue
-XshowSettings:properties
                  show all property settings and continue
-XshowSettings:locale
                  show all locale related settings and continue
```

The -X options are non-standard and subject to change without notice.

For example, these parameters can be obtained by -X.

How do I get -XX? What are the available parameters?

Comment: Which JDK version are you using? And to clarify, you're asking about which things are supported, and not which things are in use for an already-running JVM, right?

Answer (score 5):

use this.
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal

Comment: I know this command, but the problem is that it was obtained by consulting the JVM documentation.
I think the parameter help of Java command is missing, according to the general scheme, all can be obtained through XXX command help, but the Java command is not so.